# Firebase functions end point returning an empty object from server but working in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was creating an API using firebase functions and express JS. In the express, I have a number of GET routes that fetches the data from the internet using Axios. In addition to that one GET route **scrape** a site using Axios and JSDOM and returns an array of objects.

I'm using async-await modifiers to run the code in an asynchronous manner. However, all the other endpoints are returning proper data but scraping one not.

From the console, it's actually going inside the response then callback but returning an empty object. Also from the firebase console, I got to know that it's logging an error `"Error: Request failed with status code 503Error"`.

Code:

```
index.js
//To get crypto news
app.get("/crypto-news", (req,res) => {
    return cryptoNews.getLatesCryptoNews().then(async(response) => {
        console.log("News arrived") //Which is actually logging in console
        return Promise.resolve(res.json({data: response}));
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Failed to fetch")
        return res.send("Failed to fetch from API");
    })
});

//Firebase 
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

```
cryptoNews.js

//Get nse equity data
async function getLatesCryptoNews() {

    try {
        let response = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `https://tracemycode.com/`,
            json: true
        });

        if (await response) {
            const dom = new JSDOM(response.data);
            const document = dom.window.document;
            const posts = document.querySelectorAll("div.news-posts");

            //Check emptiness
            if (posts.length !== 0) {
                let data = [];

                console.log("Posts not empty"); //not loggin in console
                
                //Go through each node and get data
                posts.forEach(item => {
                    let time = item.querySelector('div.news-post-time p').textContent;
                    let title = item.querySelector('div.news-post-title h1').textContent;


                    //Push to array
                    data.push({
                        "title": (title !== null && typeof title === "string") && title,
                        "time":( time !== null && typeof time === "string") && time.substring(1, time.length - 1),
                    });
                });
                console.log("Sending data") //not logging in console
                return Promise.resolve(data);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err + "Error");
    }
}

exports.getLatesCryptoNews = getLatesCryptoNews;
```

I wonder why it's working fine in the localhost and not in the firebase functions server.

Comment: Apologies for that.

Comment: if you are scraping html, then why is `json: true` ?

Comment: That's for getting the data in JSON format so that I can access the data key from the object to pass into JSDOM to parse HTML.